# Field without Used in data in Fields Report

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I had several fields on content that had an empty *Used in* in  `/admin/reports/fields`. Apart from being inelegant :-), it's a real problem because Views doesn't see them properly as belonging to content (and it will probably cause other problems down the line, that's only what was apparent now).

After contemplating different ways to solve it (the field-related commands on Drush are unusable, probably not yet ported), I did it manually in the database with a combination of cloning and replacing. All are done but `body` because, obviously, the UI doesn't allow me to specify field names without the `field` prefix.

So, I know that this is probably the result of some settings gone wrong, what actually makes Drupal think a field is used in a type? I couldn't locate the exact setting .yml yet. Storage.node.body.yml and the others actually don't show anything really different for body and all the others that are already correct now.

By the way, not some stale data of cache or drush entup.

I am in `Drupal\field_ui\FieldStorageConfigListBuilder` right now with a little dump:

```
if ($field_storage->getName() == 'body' && $entity_type_id != 'block_content') {
  ksm($field_storage->getBundles());
}
```

It returns an empty array. Khm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm on the right track after a bit of sleuthing. `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap()` reveals that the final knowledge comes from `entity.definitions.bundle_field_map`. I won't write where it dwells because we're performing heart surgery here... But he who dares will find it. :-)